# Free SMS library on java

Tags: java, web-services, sms

Does anyone know of a java API that I could download in order to send a free SMS to a mobile number ?
If non could be found, is there a Web Service I could connect to that would do the job ?

The things is that I want to send a pin code to a user's phone in order to complete his/her registration for my mobile application, exactly how whatsapp does it (Insert phone number, receive SMS with unique pincode), but I am not yet willing to pay for an SMS service like simple wire during the development phase.

Thanks.

Comment: if you are not willing to invest you will not earn.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in development phase you do not need to test the reliability of SMS infrastructure. What your application need is an [Mock object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object). Such object will provide the necessary data your application. When you product will be ready then swap the mock with real service.

Comment: Yes, it is what I am doing right now.